# iOS - Why table view doesn't show?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I'm new to iOS programming and I'm learning to use storyboard to design the UI.

I haven't wrote any code yet because all things done by now is in the storyboard.

The program is a `Tabbed Application` and I replaced the first view by a `UITableView` and segued it to the initial view controller.

The whole structure is like:

[image]

But when I run it in the simulator, the table view showed without any content(**I have several table view cells, as you can see in the first picture**).

[image]

I can't figured out what's wrong?

Comment: Add delegate method to tableview

Comment: This is a good tutorial for beginners http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-create-a-simple-table-view-app/

Comment: Check my answer @penguin-penpen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you write some code, it would be hard to see those cells

First of all, drag an outlet from tableView to respective viewController and name it tableView.

To do that, select your custom TableViewClass in your storyboard, this will allow you to drag your outlet to that class file
[image]

then:

```
class TableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {...}
```

conform to these two protocols by implementing both

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Also don't forget to add

```
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
self.tableView.delegate = self;
```

inside your

> ViewDidLoad()
>   method

Comment: I created a `TableViewController` and add the code in the `ViewDidLoad()` method but it did no effect? How to link the class to the table view in my storyboard?

Comment: Something strange happened. I can't drag the table view to the `.h` file using `ctrl`.

Answer (score 1):

Select tableview in storyboard and Add like this delegate method.

**Option A:**

```
//.h file
@interface Tableviewcontroller : UIViewController< UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

//.M file
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
    yourtablename.delegate = self;
    yourtablename.datasource = self;
    }
```

**Option B:**

[image]

Comment: Solution B is not working for me. But solution A does help!

Answer (score 0):

please add datasource and delegate to self in `ViewDidLoad` or through storyboard it works for you

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
yourtablename.delegate = self;
yourtablename.datasource = self;
}
```